# prestashop css vertical and horizontal centering

Tags: css, geometry, prestashop, centering

Hi i need help with centering few images on my prestashop webpage.

I need help with 3 circles on bottom of the page (not with social icons) . I don't how center the images in circles.

Please help

Comment: You should not link to your live site, instead share the relevant code inside the question.

Comment: Try to add this css to the circles. line-height: circle height; and text-align:center;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for absolute position those images inside their container, and work your way from there like so:

- position: relative for `.certifikat` class, so any absolute positioned children, will be bound to their container
- position: absolute for `<img>` inside the `.certifikat` class

So to wrap it up, for the `.certifikat` class use:

```
.certifikat{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*rest of your code*/
}
```

If you know the width and height of these `<img>` tags, you can center them by:

```
.certifikat img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin-left: -(halftheirwidth);
    margin-top: -(halftheirheight);
}
```

**OR** if you don't know their exact width and height you can use the *translate* method:

```
.certifikat img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Hope this points you in the right direction

Comment: @Richard no problem-o, glad to help out!